# I'm not being able to open images in PyCharm editor to add to my program (MacBook)

Tags: python, image, pygame, pycharm, png

I'm not able to add in images to my programme in Pycharm, I've imported Pygame *and* os and it wouldn't work. The image is in .png format 64 bit from flaticon.com

Is there something else I need to do to be able to add it in, I was following a PyGame tutorial online since I'm a beginner in programming

The python launcher just glitches when I add anything to do with an image. everything else works perfectly fine.

Here is the entire code of the project so far:

```
import pygame
import os


pygame.init()  


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))


pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders - GAME ONE (PyGame)")


playerImg = pygame.image.load('space-invaders.png')
playerX = 370
playerY = 480

running = True
while running:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False

screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
pygame.display.update()
```

this is the error message:

```
 playerImg = pygame.image.load('space-invaders.png')
 pygame.error: Couldn't open space-invaders.png

 Process finished with exit code 1
```

it just glitches with any addition of an image. If I remove all image related code, it works fine
Also, import os just greys out in the editor

Comment: I did not understand from your question, does the image show up on the screen or not? And could you upload part when you `blit` it on the screen

Comment: The entire window just closes, turns on and off, too fast to see if the image is even on the screen. I do not understand what you mean with the blit part

Comment: Ok, in order to display the picture on the screen you need to "blit" it, "pygame.surface.blit()". This behaviour with opening and closing the window too fast, looks like you have some problem with the main_loop. Could you please provide these parts of your code and if not too long paste your whole code

Comment: Alright, I'll add it to the main post

Answer (score 0):

First check if the image is in the same folder as your `.py`. Next, make sure the image is really `.png` not just renamed for example, check this by trying to load another image. Last but not the least, check the spelling, maybe the name of the picture is misspelled. Since you are not using paths I can't remember anything else that could cause the issue.

Also, I do not know if it is the mistake during the copy process but last 2 lines of code need to be inside the for loop. And why you have imported `os`?

EDIT: Answer to the OP question in the comment

By importing `os` you can now use this module, nothing more. Here is how you can locate your `.png` file:

```
current_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__) #The location of your `.py`

img_dir = os.path.join(current_dir, "img_dir") #Path to the folder where your `png` is

player_img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_dir, "space-invaders.png"))
```

Instead of "img_dir" you need to put the name of your folder, or the path, depending on the folder location.

Comment: Alright, but how do I add it in as the same folder as the .py...
I thought importing os would let me get into my os and reach the picture, but yes, it doesn't seem to work

Comment: You can copy/cut it to your folder where the `.py` is, or you can using `os` get the relative path to the file, I will edit the answer and write there. But I advise before using paths just put it in the same folder to check if it is working.